# How do I output the calories information from FatSecret API based on the detected food?

Tags: python, android, flutter, rest, yolo

I want to develop an android mobile apps which be able to detect food image and output its name and calories. For example, my mobile apps detected the image as Fried Chicken, after recognizing the name of the food, it would display the Fried Chicken's calories information.

For the backend, I've already trained my custom YOLOv4 model (to detect the object ofc) and the frontend would be the UI that is currently build with **Flutter**. As of now, I know how to integrate Yolov4 model to my Flutter app by converting the model into *tflite* model (correct me if 'm wrong here).

So far, my YOLOv4 is able to predict the name of the food detected based on the images. But I want my apps also to be able to output the calorie based on the food detected which I'll be retrieving from the FatSecret database using their API.

Can someone enlighten me as to how do I associate my android apps with the FatSecret API? Also, where do I build this API, is it on the backend (with python) or the frontend (with Flutter)? I'm still new on this platform. Let me know if you need me to provide any further information. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you need capture the image on frontend (Flutter) sends to backend and show the results on the screen

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @LaksCastro does it means I should build the FatSecret API on the backend with the python language?

Comment: yes, exactly. You should put your IA model in your backend. Frontend should be only responsible by capturing the image, send to backend and show the results (backend response). The backend is where you should process the image.